# How to create an IDWriteTextLayout4?

Tags: c++, directwrite

We create an IDWriteFactory7 CComPtr interface:

```
CComPtr<IDWriteFactory7>                    _writeFactory;

_hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(_writeFactory), reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&_writeFactory));
```

Creating the Factory works.
But if we try to create an IDWriteTextLayout4, with this Factory:

```
CComPtr<IDWriteTextLayout4> _textLayout;

_writeFactory->CreateTextLayout(
                wtext.c_str(),      // The string to be laid out and formatted.
                wcslen(wtext.c_str()),  // The length of the string.
                _textFormat,  // The text format to apply to the string (contains font information, etc).
                size.width,         // The width of the layout box.
                size.height,        // The height of the layout box.
                &_textLayout  // The IDWriteTextLayout interface pointer.
            );
```

The CreateTextLayout(..) Method does not work with IDWriteTextLayout4, but instead expects  IDWriteTextLayout.

Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: What happens if you do _textLayout->QueryInterface for IDWriteTextLayout?

Comment: Define `_textLayout` as `IDWriteTextLayout`, call `CreateTextLayout(...)` and then `_textLayout->QueryInterface(&_textLayout4);`

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine!

Comment: Where did you find IDWriteTextLayout4 defined?

Answer (score 0):

Comments of systemcpro and Simon Mourier solved the Problem.